# Word random api doesn't give me the next word

Tags: javascript, api

I have a small project that works as follows:

- Generate a random word that comes from a database
- check each letter in that word
- if all letters are correct, generate another random word and repeat the game.
  just like hangman game.

So, the issue is when I am about to generate the second word, it somehow combines the first one. For instance, let say the first word is `fizz`. game starts and guessed all the letters. the second word is generated as `buzz`. I see that the second word is generated fine. but when I try to guess the letters, somehow it also checks the first word as well. It sees as `fibuzz`.
My goal is to generate a new random word everytime when I guess all the letters.

my API:

```
class API{
    static baseURL = "api-url"

     static generateRandomWord() {
        var len = 0
        var rndIndex = 1;

        fetch(API.baseURL)
        .then(response => response.json()) 
        .then(words => {
            len = words.length;
            rndIndex = this.getRandomIndex(len);
            console.log(words[rndIndex]);
        });
    }

}
```

I call this as `API.generateRandomWord()` to generate a new random word.
my events for all letters as buttons:

```
button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
   e.target.disabled = true
   let value = e.target.value

    // letter guess logic here
    
})
```

events are working as expected. The issue is again, it works fine for the first initial random word, but when we move on to the second word, the first and second word are being mixed.

What I did was add some logics to the button events like if there is a word previously, delete it. And I also tried to remove the div that holds the random word. So far those didn't help. Any help is appriciated.

EDIT:
the way that I handle the API is as below:
Basically passing the generated random word to `Word` class constructor.

```
.....
.then(words => {
   len = words.length
   rndIndex = this.getRandomIndex(len);
   console.log(words[rndIndex]);
   
   new Word(words[rndIndex])
});
```

Then this Word class start to game.

```
class Word{
    static all = []

    constructor(wordObject){
        this.name = wordObject.name
        this.id = wordObject.id
        this.category = wordObject.category
        Word.all.push(this); // this is the array I store the word each time
        this.space = this.renderSpace(); // this is the starting point.
    }

.... // other functions and logic
}
```

Comment: can you please show how and where you're calling `API.generateRandomWord()`? Basically I'd like to see the code

Comment: @theTerribleSWE, just added the code to the post. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Maybe" the reason is that your `Word` class is caching all the words in its static property `all`. Your event isn't actually able to remove any previous word because your delete logic is incorrect. So, it ends up checking against letters of "all the generated words", instead of letters of "only" the current random word

**There may be 2 solutions to this:**

1. Check your delete logic in the event to make sure it's mutating `all` and deleting the previous word. You could try using

```
Word.all.shift();
```

But I highly doubt you would have missed this. This brings me to my next point

2. Tweak the way your code is designed to avoid weird side effects :

To generate a new random word each time and only access that new word in your event, it would be better if your `static` property was an object, instead of an array. So, you'd have :

```
class Word {
    static currentWord = {}
    constructor(wordObject){
        Word.currentWord = wordObject;
    }
}
```

Now every time you generate a new word, `Word.currentWord` is reset to be this new word. You don't have to worry about deleting the previous word in your event anymore

So now your event could look like this:

```
button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
   e.target.disabled = true
   let value = e.target.value
   console.log(Word.currentWord); // accessing current Random Word
    // letter guess logic here
})
```